# can not get element by getElementById in beforeDestroy lifecycle vue

Tags: vue.js

I use `document.getElementById` in `beforeDestroy` lifecycle to get an element. But `getElementById` returns null. If I use `ref`, I can get the element. Is there any difference between them? Why document.getElementById can't get the element?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I thought the beforeDestroy hook was the right place to kill event listeners before leaving the component. For my surprise, when the route changes, the component is already unmounted when this hook is called.
This is vue.js version 2, I don’t know if it is better in version 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the timing and there could be many reasons for that.

But in your case , The `ref` was still in the virtual DOM object, which will be destroyed within the `destroy` event (Unlike the document template).

That would be one reason Vue recommends to use `$refs` if possible.

Comment: There is an issue with the timing and there could be many reasons for that.

Very nice explanation.